# Question about solution to matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-equations

[image]
In the question above, I am unsure how the very first step of the solution came about. How does fact that R is in reduced row echelon form help deduce the value of d?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall that for the general solution of a linear system is given by

$$x=x_p+x_h$$

with

- $x_p$ particular solution such that $$Ax_p=b$$
- $x_h$ homogeneous solution such that $$Ax_h=0$$

ans since R has rank $1$ it is equal to

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

What can we conclude now?

Comment: I'm really sorry this might be a trivial question, but I still can't seem to deduce anything.

Comment: @JavierLim Firstly you need to have clear how the complete solution for a linear system work. Have you clear the mening of the terms for $$x=x_p+c_1x_{h1}+c_2x_{h2}$$

Comment: $x_p$ stands for the particular solution, so $Ax_p = b$ and 
$c_1x_{h1} + c_2x_{h2}$ stand for vectors in the nullspace of $A$, correct?

Comment: @JavierLim Exactly! Then also for $R$ we have that $Rx_p=d$ and $Rx_h=0$ . Now you need to figure out what $R$ is.

Comment: Ahh, thank you! I was thinking too hard. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JavierLim That's fine! Well done. Bye